# Karate BDD framework throwing NPE with simple configuration

Tags: java, bdd, karate

I'm trying to use the Karate BDD framework for running tests on my API suite and I'm running into an NPE. As far as I can tell, I haven't misconfigured anything, but I'm sure I've overlooked something.  Given the below feature file and task runner, is there something that I've done wrong?

**Update:** this works with Karate 0.2.9 but not the latest currently 0.5.0.2

**Feature File: .../src/test/resources/root/feature/sanity.feature**

```
Feature: Sanity Check
  As a developer
  I want to ensure that the test framework is active
  So that I can be confident I am testing correctly

  Background:
    * url httpBin

  Scenario: httpBin reflection
    Given path '/anything/foo/bar?baz=quux'
    When method GET
    Then status 200
    And match response contains { "args": {"baz":"quux"}}
    And match response contains { "method": "GET" }
```

**Driver: .../src/test/java/root/feature/sanity/SmokeTest.java**

```
package root.feature.sanity;

import com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

/**
 * Created by williamspaul on 8/29/17.
 */
@RunWith(Karate.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"})
public class SmokeTest {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {}

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() {}

}
```

**mvn test output**

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running root.feature.sanity.SmokeTest
10:46:08.568 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.cucumber.CucumberRunner - init test class: class apigee.feature.sanity.SmokeTest
10:46:08.680 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.cucumber.CucumberRunner - loading feature: /(private-path)/target/test-classes/root/feature/sanity/sanity.feature
Feature: Sanity Check
  As a developer
  I want to ensure that the test framework is active
  So that I can be confident I am testing correctly

  Background:     # apigee/feature/sanity/sanity.feature:6
    * url httpBin

0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0.000s

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.389 sec <<< FAILURE!
Feature: Sanity Check  Time elapsed: 0.11 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intuit.karate.cucumber.CucumberUtils.afterStep(CucumberUtils.java:148)
    at com.intuit.karate.cucumber.CucumberUtils.runStep(CucumberUtils.java:140)
    at com.intuit.karate.cucumber.KarateRuntime.runStep(KarateRuntime.java:51)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.runBackground(CucumberScenario.java:59)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:42)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:102)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
    at com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate.runChild(Karate.java:60)
    at com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate.runChild(Karate.java:25)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate.run(Karate.java:66)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)


Results :

Tests in error:
  Feature: Sanity Check

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually using a beta release. Just use 0.5.0 and you will be fine.

BTW a big thanks for finding this, is fixed in the develop branch: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/158

Also do look at [this tweet](https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/902387883478097924) for details on why this before / after step hook is needed

Comment: 0.5.0 results in a RuntimeException about failing to construct a class named "karate-http.properties"

Comment: Had to include the karate-apache dependency and add a karate-http.properties file -- not something that was in the docs.

Comment: everything is in the docs. you don't need a manual properties file. remove it and see.

Comment: ah .. probably requires having the karate-apache dependency too.